# I have met a problem when I try to update diagnostics in a vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, diagnostics

I try to update the diagnostics collection in a vscode extension. I wrote the code like this:

```ts
if (vscode.window.activeTextEditor) {
    updateDiagnostics(vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document, diagnosticCollection);
}
```

The function `updateDiagnostics` is like:

```ts
function updateDiagnostics(document: vscode.TextDocument, collection: vscode.DiagnosticCollection): void {
    let diagnostics: vscode.Diagnostic[] = [];
    if (document) {
        let message = `error message`;
        let range = new vscode.Range(new vscode.Position(3,4), new vscode.Position(3,5))
        let severity = vscode.DiagnosticSeverity.Error
        let diagnostic = new vscode.Diagnostic(range, message, severity);
        diagnostics.push(diagnostic);
        collection.set(document.uri, diagnostics)
    } else {
        collection.clear();
    }
}
```

This code works, however when I put the `if` statement after an async operation like the following, the code does not work.

```ts
const respBody = await postRequest(uri,{name:"testcontraact1",contractcode:fileContent,limit:10});
if (vscode.window.activeTextEditor) {
   updateDiagnostics(vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document, diagnosticCollection);
}
```

After debugging the code, I found that the function `updateDiagnostics` has been executed, but there is no diagnostic information shown in my testing code which really confused me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the problem. After the execution of the `postRequest`, the `activeTextEditor.document` has been different. So I try this:

```ts
let dc = vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document
const respBody = await postRequest(uri,{name:"testcontraact1",contractcode:fileContent,limit:10});
updateDiagnostics(dc, diagnosticCollection);
```

And it worked!!!